MenuPicker: Change Dropdown Style (SwiftUI)
I have used this StackOverflow Post to create a custom menu picker in SwiftUI:
struct MenuPicker: View {
    @State var selection: String = "Option 1"
    let menuOptions: [String] = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            Picker(selection: $selection,
                    label: EmptyView(),
                    content: {
                        ForEach(menuOptions, id: \.self) { option in
                            Text(option)
                                .tag(option)
                        }
                    }
            )
            .pickerStyle(.automatic)
        } label: {
            Text(selection)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(.blue.opacity(0.7))
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
}

When changing the selection, the dropdown looks as follows:

How to change the appearance of the dropdown? I would like to change background color (e.g. red), text color (e.g. green), and divider (e.g. white).
